# Android 5.0.2: Windows 10 does not recognize it in USB storage mode

Tags: usb, windows, usb-connection-mode, mount

I bought `Prestigio MultiPhone 3504 Muze` with `Android 5.0.2`. When I connect it to my PC with Windows 10 installed, I can't find the device in explorer.

How to connect my phone to PC?

Comment: Did you try searching about the issue on web? You can save us the trouble by mentioning the type of solutions you may have attempted so far?

Comment: @Firelord yeah, I finally connected  it by choosing `as media device option`. But I hopped to delete all mobile contacts (sync from Google) using windows exploerer. I suppose to do that I need to connect my phone as usb storage, right?

Comment: If you want to manage your contacts you can do that directly using your phone's Contact app or by visiting https://contacts.google.com for managing your synched contacts.

Comment: @Lucky I want to delete all contacts synced from Google

Comment: You can do that in your phone itself. Just customize the contacts to dissolution only the contacts stored in the phone. And stop syncing your contacts from/to Google.

Comment: @Lucky I've already stopped syncing from Google. But it imported about thousand contacts. How to delete them all at once?

Answer (score 2):

For your device to be shown as USB storage you need to set MTP as your usb-computer connection option.

Settings - Storage - Press three dots - USB Computer connection - Select Media device (MTP)

Now when you connect it to your Windows 10 PC you will be able to see the device's storage.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do with new windows 10 not detecting Android phone is, install below two KBs and restart.
Step1.  install: 'KB3010081' ---> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3010081
Restart
Step 2. install: 'KB3099229'---> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229
Restart
And you are done. Open My computer and you will see MTP logical drive in there.
After one more reboot, you may see your phone model/ make as drive label.
Thanks and enjoy!
Rupesh Diwaker